# How does a developer adopt an orphan module?

Tags: community-official-site

Is there any way for a developer to apply for adoption of an orphan module?

Some modules like the [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php/) module are still actively used by many sites, but there isn't any active maintainer on it.

I searched for [Drupal orphan module adoption](https://www.google.com/search?q=drupal+orphan+module+adoption) but saw no relevant result. Hence I'm asking for advice here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions explicitly asking to recommend, find or compare a module, theme, distribution, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Drupal Answers. Research and testing needs to be done before asking a question. Please describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: The question is about documentation searching. I've Googled and search the website for proper instructions. Apparently I couldn't find it with the choice of keywords.

Comment: Notice that saying the question is about documentation searching is saying the question is off-topic.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: "How to adopting an orphan module", although not coding related, is definately a "Drupal development/theming how-tos". So I believe it's very much [on-topic](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I wasn't asking for a "how to search for documentation", but I was asking for a specific piece of information I cannot find in documentation, not much different from other coding problems. It is a question that has a clear answer. I've shown my work. And the answer would be useful to other developers with similar problem. This is a perfectly legitimate question for this site.

Comment: That is different from _The question is about documentation searching_ which is essentially saying _I am asking where to find the documentation I need_, and it's not an on-topic request. I would avoid adding such sentences, or users could think the question is asking for something that is considered off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a well-established process for this. As this process may change, it is best to refer to the official documentation to guide you. Please read [Taking over unsupported (abandoned) projects](https://www.drupal.org/node/251466)